# How to call ajax from script to insert user input into mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a table inside a form, once a button is clicked a function is called that confirms the contents of the user input (checking to ensure all fields have info).  After proceeding through the if statements and no errors are present I want to write the user information to mysql.

I have written the ajax file (see below) and I think my error is how I call the ajax file. Nothing is getting written to the database table and I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
<?php 
include_once("config.php"); 
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$date = $_POST['tDate'];    
$species = $_POST['tSpecies'];
$sqrNum = $_POST['tSqrNum'];
$lat = $_POST['tLat'];  
$lng = $_POST['tLng'];  
$cond = $_POST['tCond'];
$num = $_POST['tNum'];
$hab = $_POST['tHab'];  
$behav = $_POST['tBahav'];
$reg = $_POST['tReg'];

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO species_reported (date, species, square_num, lat, long, condition, numbers_obs, habitat, behavior, region)
    VALUES ('{$date}', '{$species}', '{$sqrNum}', '{$lat}', '{$lng}', '{$cond}', '{$hab}', '{$behav}', '{$reg}')"); 

?>
```

and from within the script

```
else{ 
    //$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"ajax_write.php",
        data:"date=" + tDate  +"&Species="+ tSpecies +"&SqrNum="+ tSqrNum +"&lat=" + tLat + "&lng=" + tLng + "&cond=" + tCond +"&num=" + tNum + "&hab=" + tHab + "&behav=" + tBahav + "&reg=" + tReg,
        dataType: "dataString",
        cache: "true",
        success: function(msg,string,jqXHR){
            $("#results").html(msg+string+jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

}

EDIT... I checked my php log and am seeing Undefined index: tSpecies (as well as all other Post['thisHere'].  If this is any help to resolving the issue.  My understanding was that I could send the data as I have and ajax would allocate contents to the variables in the php file (ie. from jscript.."date=" tDate would get sent to the xjax file and assign the value of tDate (from javascript) to the php variable $date.

Comment: wow, it seems you posted everything you knew, the whole your project! It's not good attitude to other people, whom you asking. Please, edit your question, and keep only meaningful information, it's not clear what you asking about, and where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The indexes you use in `$_POST` have to match the parameter names in the `$.ajax` `data:` parameter. You have `date=`, `Species=`, etc. in the parameter, but you're trying to access `$_POST['tDate']`,  `$_POST['tSpecies']`, etc. You need to change one of them to match the other.

Also, I recommend you use an object rather than a string as the `data:` parameter. The values need to be URL-encoded if they contain special characters, and you're not doing that. If you use an object, jQuery takes care of formatting and encoding it for you. So it should be:

```
data: { tDate: tDate, tSpecies: tSpecies, tSqrNum: tSqrNum, ... },
```

BTW, EcmaScript6 provides a shorthand for objects where the property names are the same as the variables containing their values:

```
data: { tdate, tSpecies, tSqrNum, ... },
```

Comment: Many thanks Barmar, this appears to have resolved the PHP errors but the user input is still not getting written to the database table.  I updated my jscript as follows data: {tDate: tDate, tSpecies: tSpecies, tSqrNum:tSqrNum, tLat:tLat, tLng:tLng, tCond:tCond, tNum:tNum, tHab:tHab, tBehav:tBehav, tReg: tReg}, and updated my php as $lng = $_POST['tLng']; so if I understand this, I am sending tDate (of value var tDate in jscript) to the php file where $date will be set to the value of the sent tDate; So if tDate has data, that should get copied over and inserted into mysql?

Comment: Yes, it should. Maybe your query is getting an error. Add `or die(mysqli_error($con)` to the end of the `mysqli_query` line. I also recommend that you use a prepared statement with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` instead of putting variables into the query.

Comment: so I tossed in an insert line I copied from phpadmin into the ajax file, and when called from the javascript, it creates the record on the database.  Thanks for all your help barmar, its this last piece of the puzzle I need to get working to wrap this up.  Would my table configuration be causing issues (INT, DATE...) ???

Comment: I am at a loss now...I deleted the table, created it again, created two columns ID and name, added details for name as up above, commented out all other code, ran the script that calls the xml...wrote it to the database, added in all the other columns, ran it again with that included...nothing.

Comment: No way for me to tell what's going wrong from what you've written. Are you getting an error when you add `or die` to the script?

Comment: The issue appears to be with the database, it would appear that if one value cant be populated in the table, none of the other values can.  That being said, what is the best way to store a negative number (ie longitude of - value and 19 numbers)

Comment: I managed to resolve it, not sure what the problem was but deleting the table and starting from scratch resolved the issue.  Thanks for all your help with this